# How to get all combinations of keys of nested maps with Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

Assuming I have a `Map<Integer, Map<Class, String>>` how could I get all combinations of the `Integer` keys of the outer map and the keys of all maps which are values of outer map in one elegant (but probably long) Java stream declaration?

My approaches:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Class, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.keySet().stream()
        .map(intKey -> map.get(intKey).keySet().stream()
                .map(classKey -> new SimpleEntry(intKey, classKey)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

collects a list of `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline`. With

```
map.keySet().stream()
        .map(intKey -> map.get(intKey).keySet().stream()
                .map(classKey -> new SimpleEntry(intKey, classKey))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have trouble wrapping my head around the collection of already collected `SimpleEntry`s. Of course, the approach can be wrong completely.

My problems is that I simply don't find a way to solve this. Please note that I'm not looking for a workaround as I want to broaden my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need a `flatMap()`:

```
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(c -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), c)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Just for fun, here's the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) solution:

```
EntryStream.of(map)
        .mapValues(Map::keySet)
        .flatMapValues(Set::stream)
        .toList()
```